# Table.Autofilter with using part of the cells.value

Tags: vba, filter, excel-formula, listbox

I would like to filter a table / range containing e-mail addresses using only the domains of these addresses. The domains of these e-mail addresses are selected using the listbox "list box 9". My code works if I have selected 1 or 2 items from this listbox, but with 3 or more it does not work.

I suspect it is case of a "*" used for the search, but I have no idea how to solve it.

```
Dim wb, wbR As Workbook
Dim Sht, RSht As Worksheet
Dim ListU As ListBox
Dim i As Long
Dim totalSelected  As Long
Dim selectedItems As Variant
Dim selectedCounter As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim Rng As Excel.Range


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Sht = wb.Worksheets(1)


Set ListU = Sht.ListBoxes("List Box 9") ' has the same information as Rng
lastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb.Sheets(4).Columns("F:F"))
Set Rng = Range(wb.Sheets(4).Cells(2, 5), wb.Sheets(4).Cells(lastRow, 5)) ' the column with email domains eg. "@dom.com"

'find selected items in a list box
For i = 1 To ListU.ListCount
    If ListU.Selected(i) Then
        
        totalSelected = totalSelected + 1
    End If
Next i


' Add the selected items to an array

ReDim selectedItems(totalSelected - 1)
For i = 1 To ListU.ListCount
    If ListU.Selected(i) Then
        
        selectedItems(selectedCounter) = "*" & ListU.List(i) ' I will use this in a table with the full email address eg. "abc@dom.com"
        selectedCounter = selectedCounter + 1
    End If
Next i


Set wbR = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\address.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)

Set RSht = wbR.Worksheets(1)


' Filter the table using the array of selected items
RSht.Range("A:G").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=selectedItems, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution to this case, so I made a loop.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim ListaUI As ListBox
Dim i As Long
Dim totalSelected, totalSelected2  As Long
Dim selectedItems, selectedItems2 As Variant
Dim selectedCounter, selectedCounter2 As Long
Dim wbR As Workbook
Dim RSht As Worksheet
Dim DL As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Sht = wb.Worksheets(1)
Set ListaUI = Sht.ListBoxes("List Box 9")
Set RSht = wbR.Worksheets(1)
Set wbR = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\address.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)


For i = 1 To ListaUI.ListCount
    If ListaUI.Selected(i) Then
        
        totalSelected = totalSelected + 1
    End If
Next i


' Add the selected items to an array
ReDim selectedItems(totalSelected - 1)
For i = 1 To ListaUI.ListCount
    If ListaUI.Selected(i) Then
        
        selectedItems(selectedCounter) = ListaUI.List(i)
        selectedCounter = selectedCounter + 1
    End If
Next i


'add selected to the filter
ReDim selectedItems2(selectedCounter - 1)
For i = 2 To lastRow

    
        DL = InStr(wb.Sheets(4).Cells(i, 5), ".") - 1
        selectedItems2(selectedCounter2) = "*" & Left(Rng.Item(i - 1), DL) & "*" ' in this way I have the part of the email address, the one before the dot
        RSht.Range("A:G").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=selectedItems2, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        RSht.Range(Range("G3"), Range("G3").End(xlDown)).Copy
        With wb.Sheets(2)
        If .Range("G1").Value = "" Then
            .Range("G1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=True, Transpose:=False
      
        End With
        End If
    
Next i
```